# Internal works of ASP.NET Validation controls in client and server side

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to know how ASP.NET validation controls are working (eg: requiredfield validator, regular expression validator). What will really happening when clicking on the button? What are the events are fireing on client side? What really happening internally?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button (if you you defined CausesValidation="true") button send request to server with __doPostBackWithOptions function aims which contains valiadtion group as parameter (if you defined ValidationGroup property for your button). __doPostBackWithOptions contains  function Page_ClientValidate. In this case will be checked all validators which belong for this group. If result (Page_IsValid) will be true postback occures. If You don't define validationGroup (but CausesValidation true) will be checked all validators which is present on page.  If   defined CAusesValidation false will  use _doPostBack function without validators checking. 
More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338815(v=vs.71).aspx and 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: Where validations actually happening? client side or server side? If client side means, what really happening?

Comment: The validation happens for both client-side and server side. On server side you can call Page.Validate() and check Page.IsValid  and do some action if true or skip action if false. For Page.Validate(string validationgroupname) you can define parameter validation group name. On client-side validation prevents postback  if data is incorrect but you have to check it again on server side because if client browser works with unplugged javascript validation doesn't occurred in this case